# Querying JSON with SelectToken and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have a bunch of financial data in json format and need to extract two pieces of information from it:

- the `ticker symbols` (e.g. AAPL, GOOG)
- the `industry` that each stock belongs to.

Here's the [link](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.industry%20where%20id%20in%20(select%20industry.id%20from%20yahoo.finance.sectors)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys) to the data and below you can see what the data looks like in a json viewer:

[image]

Here's my latest (non-working) attempt to retrieve the `industry names`:

```
string url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.industry%20where%20id%20in%20(select%20industry.id%20from%20yahoo.finance.sectors)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
IList<string> industries = o.SelectToken("query.results.industry").Select(s => (string)s).ToList();
```

How can I retrieve the `ticker symbols` and `industry names`and store them in a convenient way (e.g. as string arrays or in a dictionary)?

Comment: `It's broken. Fix it for me.` - What result are you getting? Have you tried breaking your chained calls into atomic assignments? What does `o.SelectToken` actually give you? I'm thinking it's not a string, so casting to a string seems like a bad idea here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` might be well suited for this. If not, this should at least give you an idea of how to select the information you need:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> industryData =
    o.SelectToken("query.results.industry")
        .ToDictionary(
            ind => ind["name"].ToString(),
            ind => ind["company"] != null ? 
                   ind["company"].Select(c => c["symbol"].ToString()) : null);
```

The conditional is necessary because there's (at least) one industry with zero companies (and no name for that matter). This will give you a dictionary who's keys are industry names and who's values are an `IEnumerable<string>` of stock tickers.